# Windows store app for all resolution

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, viewbox

I trying to make my application working for all resolution for that I used ViewBox .
But ViewBox is not adapting the size of screen.It's somewhat bigger than the screen.
How page should appear for all resolutions :[image]

But Problem is with increasing or decreasing the resolution the page willn't fit to screen inspite showing gridview scroller to scroll.CODE :-

```
<GridView>
<ViewBox Stretch="Fill" >
<GridViewItem>
...
</GridViewItem>
</ViewBox>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Viewbox should be applied on entire grid or gridview.

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both">
    <GridView>
         <GridViewItem>
              ...
         </GridViewItem>
    </GridView>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: But then I won't be able to change it's portrait and snapped mode.

Comment: I can't understand what are you saying.

Comment: I mean to say that If I put my gridview in viewbox ,it will work fine in landscape mode but If I like to use same gridview in Portrait mode then page will adapt paortrait mode's resolution inspite of showing the gridview.

Comment: You can write logic such that viewbox should not be applied in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

You should put everything into standard `Grid`, anchor this to device borders (left,right, top, bottom).